# Bayes' Theorem help! How can I prove that P(A) in the denominator is equivalent to the Total Probability Theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As I understand it, the formula of Bayes' Theorem is generally expressed as:

$$\mathsf P(B_i\mid A) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid B_i)~\mathsf P(B_i)}{\mathsf P(A)}$$

Yet some reference material says that the theorem can also be expressed as the following since we do not always know the value of $P(A)$:

> $$\mathsf P(B_i\mid A) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid B_i)~\mathsf P(B_i)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mathsf P(A\mid B_i)~\mathsf P(B_i)}$$

I noticed that this denominator is essentially the Total Probability Theorem. Could somebody please provide a proof showing that $~\mathsf P(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mathsf P(A\mid B_i)~\mathsf P(B_i)~$ by the Total Probability Theorem? I am very lost on this and would love some guidance.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Erm it is actually: $P(B_i\mid A) = \dfrac{P(B_i)~P(A\mid B_i)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(B_i)~P(\color{blue}{A\mid B_i})}$  but presumably that was just a typo.

Comment: The statement "P(A) = Total Probability Theorem" makes **absolutely no sense**.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Meh. It's not a well formed statement, but I did get the sense that Anon meant "what P(A) equals, via the Total Probability Theorem."

Comment: @GrahamKemp: yes, no doubt the OP meant something. but part of the reason (s)he is confused is the imprecise use of language. there are at least two possible questions here. (1) why is the total probability theorem true? / how does one prove the total probability theorem? (2) why can I use the total probability theorem in this setting? clarifying the source of the confusion is the first step to dispelling it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I'm totally new to latex and had some issues with the formatting. In regards to symplectomorphic's answer, I was looking more at #1. My goal is to try to prove the Total Probability Theorem using Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by $\#1$? Also, proving TPT using Bayes' Theorem seems illogical, especially since Bayes' extended/generalized theorem uses TPT.

Comment: @probablyme I meant in symplectomorphic's answer, where he suggested that I had "at least two possible questions," the first suggestion.

So it is not possible for me to prove the TPT using Bayes' Theorem? If it helps, I'm trying to prove that $~\mathsf P(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mathsf P(A\mid B_i)~\mathsf P(B_i)~$. Is that not possible?

Comment: @Anon: Your use of LaTeX was fine; Kemp's edits were minor. However, as pointed out by probablyme, the question you are asking is very strange. Indeed, the yellow-box Bayes' theorem follows from the no-box Bayes' Theorem by **applying** the TPT. So using them to *prove* the TPT is probably circular. (For what it's worth, you *can* use the two Bayes' theorems to prove TPT. I'm just arguing that you *shouldn't* :P)

Comment: The proof of TPT is already provided by XKX.

Comment: @Anon As for how/why, the answer posted seems fine. [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Total_Probability_Theorem) is another proof; looks like the same thing (I just skimmed them). Also, there was a typo earlier, that I didn't notice, by I did mention that the denominator is true _by_ TPT

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help! I've finally made sense of this... I apologize for all the initial confusion but I really appreciate the responses.

Comment: The formula is severely ambiguous, please replace it by $$\mathsf P(B_i\mid A) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid B_i)~\mathsf P(B_i)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\mathsf P(A\mid B_k)~\mathsf P(B_k)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The formulae above aren't correct. In the first I suppose you meant to write $B_i$ on the left hand side? In the second, the numerator should read $\sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i)P(A \mid B_i)$.

Pending these two changes, the second formula holds if the events $B_i$ are *mutually exclusive* and $$A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i.$$ This result is milder than the total probability theorem. To prove it, simply note that if $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$ then $$P(A) = P\left(A \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i\right) = P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_i)\right).$$ Given that $B_i$ are mutually exclusive, so are $A \cap B_i$, and as a result $$P(A) = P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_i)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A \cap B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i) P(A \mid B_i).$$

Comment: Hi there, I am confused on what you mean by $$A \subset \cup_{i=1}^n B_i.$$ and $$P(A) = P(A \cap \cup_{i=1}^n B_i) = P(\cup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_i)).$$. Could you please explain this without using the mathematical notation? I'm not very good with that...

Comment: In standard usage $\cup$ is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup$ is used in things like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$.  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: It is a little bit hard to explain all of these via words easily - you can always look up the definition of each of the notation, but you may not digest them very quickly. If you have touched the Venn's diagram before, you may try to visualize the argument as follow: Draw a rectangle, and just randomly partition the rectangle into different (irregular) pieces, just like a puzzle. Each piece denotes $B_i$ and the rectangle is the union of them. On top of that, draw a circle, or any other closed shape inside the rectangle, representing $A$ which intersecting with those $B_i$.

Comment: I for one don't see what is incorrect in the equalities in the question. There is no difference between $\Pr(B_i)\Pr(A\mid B_i)$ and $\Pr(A\mid B_i)\Pr(B_i)$, since multiplication of numbers is commutative. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The OP has edited his question. It used to be $P(B_i)P(B_i \vert A)$.

Comment: @Anon if $B_i$ are mutually exclusive and $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_i \right) = 1,$$ then basically $$P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i)P(A \vert B_i)$$ by the total probability theorem. However,  $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_i \right) = 1,$$ might be a stronger assumption than $$A \subset  \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_i.$$ The latter simply states that the events $B_i$ collectively cover all events in $A$, while the former states that the events $B_i$ collectively cover all events that have a positive probability of occurring.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\Pr(B_i\mid A) = \frac{\Pr(A\mid B_i)\Pr(B_i)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \Pr(A\mid B_i) \Pr(B_i)}
$$
The only thing I find displeasing in the equality written above is that the letter $i$ is used for two different things.  I'd rather write something like
$$
\Pr(B_i\mid A) = \frac{\Pr(A\mid B_i)\Pr(B_i)}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \Pr(A\mid B_j) \Pr(B_j)},
$$

Let us as why $\Pr(A) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \Pr(A\mid B_j) \Pr(B_j).$
\begin{align}
\Pr(A) & = \Pr( (A\ \&\ B_1) \text{ or }(A\ \&\ B_2) \text{ or } \ldots \text{ or } (A\ \&\ B_n)) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(A\ \&\ B_1) + \Pr(A\ \&\ B_2) + \cdots + \Pr(A\ \&\ B_n) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(A\mid B_1)\Pr(B_1)+\Pr(A\mid B_2)\Pr(B_2) + \cdots + \Pr(A\mid B_n)\Pr(B_n). \tag 1
\end{align}
(All this assumes that the events $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, i.e. at least one of them must be true but no two of them can both be true.)

Now notice that the line labeled $(1)$ above is the expected value of a random variable that is equal to $\Pr(A\mid B_j)$ if $B_j$ is true, for $j=1,\ldots,n$.  Thus the expected value of the conditional probability is equal to the unconditional probability. That is the law of total probability. Sometimes it is phrased thus: The prior expected value of the posterior probability of $A$ is equal to the prior probability of $A$.